# design for a PC/104 interface bus expansion

Tags: ttl, bus, io

Can someone tell my why this won't work or tell me a better way to do it? I have a TS-5500 from Technologic Systems that has a PC/104 bus which I am building a card to expand the IO ports. Pin B19 on the PC/104 bus decodes IO addresses 0x140->0x15f. I'm also using address 0x148 to latch the inputs at the 374's into the chips so I will have to read that IO address before I read any/all of the IO ports 0x140->0x143. The outputs will have 10K pull-up resistors and be protected by 5v diodes. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

B19 on the PC104 does no such thing. It is RFSH*, and is used as part of a refresh cycle for dynamic RAM. You need a decoder for A4 - A7 to do what you want.

A 373 will do exactly the opposite of what you want, since it accepts data when LEN is high, and 138 outputs are active low. Use 374s instead.

EDIT - And, of course, I forgot that the ISA bus uses 10-bit IO addressing, which was then carried over to PC104, so a decoder (not needed as long as you stick with this board) will need to operate on A4 - A9.

Comment: In the wiki page for the TS-5500 it say: "The I/O ranges of 100h - 13Fh and 200h - 26Fh are excellent choices for PC/104 daughter board I/O usage. When designing a custom PC/104 daughter board, a User Chip Select is available on PC/104 Bus pin B19 that decodes the I/O range 140h - 15Fh. This can make for a simpler and more cost-effective design."

Comment: I stand corrected. Don't you just love non-standard implementations?

Comment: Only when there's no documentation.

Comment: What happens when Technologic Systems decides to discontinue the TS-5500? You'll be stuck with a board which won't work on any other PC/104 board. It would be much safer to use the A4-A7 decoder as WRB has suggested.

Comment: This is just a 'one-off' wire-wrap. I'd actually like to do this in FPGA or CPLD. It would be so much cleaner. I've got maybe 6 or 7 other Technologic boards on the shelf that I got off of ebay pretty cheap.